# Python TypeError, Required Argument not found

Tags: python, odoo-10

I am trying to build a module that coverts A.D date to B.S date. I got the Type error `Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found`.

My code is like this

```
 class Date(models.Model):
     _name = 'date'
     english_date = fields.Char(required=True, string='English Date')
     nep_date = fields.Char(compute='_converttonepali', store=True,string='Nepali Date')
     @api.multi
     @api.depends('english_date')
     def _converttonepali(self):
          yearsd = 2000
          monthd = 1
          eng_date = datetime.date(int(self.english_date))
          dayslapsed = (datetime.date(eng_date[0:4],eng_date[5:7],eng_date[8:]) - (start_english)).days

         for item in nepali_date:
            for month in range(1, 13):
                if dayslapsed >= item[month]:
                    monthd = month + 1
                    yearsd = int(item[0])
                 if monthd == 13:
                    monthd = 1
                    yearsd =yearsd + 1

    self.nep_date = str(yearsd) + '/' + str(monthd) + '/' + str(dayslapsed + 1)
    self.nep_date = datetime.date(int(self.nep_date[0:4]), int(self.nep_date[5:7]),int(self.nep_date[8:]))
    return self.nep_date
```

Hoping for the solution. Thank you all in advance.
[here is the full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EztxV.png)

Comment: Please add the full traceback as well, so we can see where the error originates.

Comment: `eng_date = datetime.date(int(self.english_date))`: as suggested by the error message, you need to supply a year, month and date to `datetime.date`, not just a year.

Comment: @Evert i guess there are three parameters while parsing the date, and yes it would be better if you post the problem stacktrace too.

Comment: I have added full traceback. Please checkout the image file :)